# Alter xml file by calling a C# function in xslt

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have a xml file and an xslt file in my website project. When I run the site, I need to call a c# function from xslt and alter the values in xml file.... Given below is my xml file.... I need to add a text (say "Mr.") in front of every firstname through a c# code.... After adding, it should reflect in the xml file.... Also, as a next step, I need to add another node in the xml file (say age) through another c# function.... Please note that the c# function should be called from my xslt file.... Can anyone help me with a simple code for this????

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <employee>
    <firstname>Kaushal</firstname>
    <lastname>Parik</lastname>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <firstname>Abhishek</firstname>
    <lastname>Swarnkar</lastname>
  </employee>
</root>
```

Comment: as far as I know there is no way to call an outside function in xsl. One possible approach although challenging is to create a custom XSL processor with additional functions to call your desired C# functions

Comment: I saw some codes like, creating a custom class in C# and adding the methods in that class.... Then these methods were called from xslt code.... But, I cant understand them....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can call C# function from .xsl file. Please refer following code.

This is your input XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<root>
<employee>
  <firstname>Kaushal</firstname>
  <lastname>Parik</lastname>
</employee>
<employee>
  <firstname>Abhishek</firstname>
  <lastname>Swarnkar</lastname>
</employee>
</root>
```

Formatting function in a C# class is like this:

```
    public class MyXslExtension
{
    public string FormatName(string name)
    {
        return "Mr. " + name;
    }
}
```

Apply following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
            xmlns:myUtils="pda:MyUtils">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="vQ">Mr. </xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="employee/firstname">
<xsl:element name="firstname">
  <xsl:value-of select="myUtils:FormatName(.)" />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And C# Functin to call Formatting function is like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XsltArgumentList arguments = new XsltArgumentList();
        arguments.AddExtensionObject("pda:MyUtils", new MyXslExtension());

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("books1.xml"))
        {
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load("transform.xslt");
            transform.Transform("books.xml", arguments, writer);
        }
    }
```

And the out put is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<root>
<employee>
<firstname>Mr. Kaushal</firstname>
<lastname>Parik</lastname>
</employee>
<employee>
<firstname>Mr. Abhishek</firstname>
<lastname>Swarnkar</lastname>  
</employee>
</root>
```

I have referred [this link](http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/Calling-C-function-in-XSL.aspx) to answer your question.

Hope this will help you.
Please mark +1 if it is useful to you....

Comment: I executed your code.... The xml file remains the same.... I want the original xml to be modified.... I dont want to create a new xml....
If the original xml is "nirav.xml", the output should also be "nirav.xml", but with the "Mr." concatenated to each name....

Comment: Great Nirav.... I got the solution.... Ur code creates a new xml named "books1.xml" and stores in C:Program Files(x86)/Common files/microsoft shared/ devserver/10.0....
Thanks a lot for taking ur time to help me....

Comment: Hi Nirav, I've another challenge for you.... Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791180/add-a-xml-node-through-xslt-or-c-sharp-code
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Add the XSL style sheet reference to your XML document, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<root>
  <employee>
    <firstname>Kaushal</firstname>
    <lastname>Parik</lastname>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <firstname>Abhishek</firstname>
    <lastname>Swarnkar</lastname>
  </employee>
</root>
```

or use [`XslTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx) class to transforms XML data using an `XSLT` from .NET:

```
//Create the XslTransform object.
XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();

//Load the stylesheet.
xslt.Load("output.xsl");

//Transform the file.
xslt.Transform("books.xml", "books.html");
```

Comment: Hi Ria, I cannot use the first method as there are too many values.... Can you give me a small example using the second method.... I am new to this, so please give a sample code for xslt file and aspx.cs file for the above xml....

Answer (score 0):

Apply following .xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="vQ">Mr. </xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee/firstname">
  <xsl:element name="firstname">
    <xsl:value-of  select="concat($vQ, .)"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<root>
<employee>
  <firstname>Kaushal</firstname>
  <lastname>Parik</lastname>
</employee>
<employee>
  <firstname>Abhishek</firstname>
  <lastname>Swarnkar</lastname>
</employee>
</root>
```

Out put is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<root>
  <employee>
  <firstname>Mr. Kaushal</firstname>
  <lastname>Parik</lastname>
</employee>
<employee>
  <firstname>Mr. Abhishek</firstname>
  <lastname>Swarnkar</lastname>
</employee>
</root>
```

and C# function is like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();  
        xslt.Load("transform.xslt");  
        xslt.Transform("books.xml", "books1.xml"); 
    }
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Hi Nirav, I need to do the concatenation in C# code and not in xslt.... Kindly see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994418/update-xml-using-xslt-in-c-sharp-how-to-update-the-same-file
It will give you more clear idea.... Sorry for the inconvenience....

Comment: Yes, I got your point. I am posting another answer. I am sure that, that answer will solve your query.

Comment: You can refer my [answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774789/update-xml-file-by-calling-a-c-sharp-function-in-xslt/11776843#11776843)